# Visual Studio crashes when editing an MVC 4 (Beta) .cshtml file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Visual Studio 11 beta crashes when editing an MVC 4 (Beta) .cshtml file.
when you press 'enter' visual studio 2011 beta crashes just in .cshtml files

Comment: Attach a debugger to it and post the exception.

Comment: explain how to debug the desenv.exe

Comment: Please report this to Microsoft at http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio

Comment: Open a second copy of VS, Tools, Attach to Process, devenv.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2012/03/06/visual-studio-11-beta-razor-editor-issue-workaround.aspx a workaround has been proposed by Microsoft themselves.

Comment: updated url: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/03/06/visual-studio-11-beta-razor-editor-issue-workaround/

Answer (score 2):

Not specific to MVC4 beta, but helped me resolve my issue with VS crashing on opening .cshtml files:

`devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs`

[The /ResetSkipPkgs switch is documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241276%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and has helped several other people resolve all kinds of problems with VS.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug that has [already been reported](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727820/vs-11-beta-any-razor-view-edit-crashes-application) to Microsoft. Hopefully it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you clean your `BIN` folder (if any files or folders exist) and build (<kbd>F6</kbd>) your solution without code error, this crush error is solved.

I did it and now I can edit my solution files...